# points within a particular distance

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, spatial-query

I have a table conatining a set of points. I would like to make a query that checks the distance between the points and if the distance is small er than the tolerance it would set the points to just one.

Any suggestions how I can accomplish such task?

The following is a graphical issue of what I have. Now I want that only one point will exist where three distinct roads meet

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So you are trying to remove points that are approximately duplicates?

Comment: @Tim Child I have edited the question to understand better my concerns

Comment: More specifically do you want to chose one the points as canonical  or an average of them?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky issue with more than one way to fix it.

One obvious strategy is to try and find unique points snapped to a virtual grid, using [ST_SnapToGrid](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_SnapToGrid.html). This technique works best with projected units (e.g., metres with UTM), but not as good with geographic coordinates (with degrees of  latitude/longitude), which have variable physical distances.

Answer (score 0):

If I understandd you right:

1)Read about [ST_Distance](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_Distance.html)

2)Write your own function, wich will use ST_Distance and maybe one of theese [algorythms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem)(a little simplified for your task)